# Laser filamentation in air

Tags: optics, photons, laser, lenses, non-linear-optics

For the non-linear optical process of filamentation in the atmosphere propagated by intense laser pulses (1TW) of ps-fs pulsewidths, what is the optimum method, through lens set-ups (or otherwise) to delay filamentation to begin the maximum distance, z, from the laser output and what is the maximum theoretical distance?

Comment: This is *extremely* broad and it has rather low chances of finding an answer here, though I can't see how you can plausibly narrow down the core of the question.

Comment: However, the pulse durations that you give definitely blow it out of the water: saying "ns-fs pulsewidths" spans some eight orders of magnitude, for a process where a change of even a factor of ten in the pulse length can have a huge effect on the propagation. You should be *way* more specific on narrowing down the laser parameters you're interested in, as well as being more clear on what is it you actually want to do with the information.

Comment: An error on my part, should have been ps-fs. The idea is to find the maximum distance and work back to the source.

Comment: Take the work of Andreas Schmitt-Sody, et al. published online 23 March 2017  by the American Institute of Physics, 1 TW, pulse duration's 0.7 to 10 ps, as parameter. (article title- Dependence of single-shot pulse durations on near-infrared filamentation-guided breakdown in air)

Comment: You can ask this question on ResearchGate may be, in the right communities.

Answer (score -1):

The standard trick is to emit a conic shaped beam.

Comment: Can you add a few more details? This is a bit too short to be an answer.

Comment: Actually, there's really no such thing as "too short to be an answer". This does seem to be aiming to answer the question to me. It doesn't give enough detail to be a particularly useful answer, but that doesn't prevent it from being an answer.